# Select a timestamp when I have only a date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has 2 columns of timestamp datatype, `start_time` and `end_time`. The format is something like *'2013-5-19 09:00:00'*.

When a user enter the date, it will be something like *2013-5-19*. How do I get the largest value for the date the user has entered?

```
Select max(end_time) from appointment
where ...
```

Comment: If the user just gives the date, then the maximum timestamp for that date will be 23:59:59 on that date.  Is that what you need?

Comment: @John, it needs to check that value in the database. So if the user wants a given date, I check first the latest appointment for that day, i.e. the biggest end_time. It's first comes, first served.

Comment: Again, does `max(end_time)` not do that?

Comment: @Juhana, that should do that if I don't care about the day. But what if user want a different day? So I need to check the latest appointment for given day, not for everyday.

Comment: I don't know PL/SQL,  but the general idea is `...WHERE end_time > (date) 00:00:00 AND end_time <= (date) 23:59:59`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the `MAX(end_time)` and also get only the records within the given date.

Here's a [working SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/713fd/59).

Or you can try this:

```
create table appointment(start_time date, end_time date);

INSERT INTO appointment(start_time, end_time) 
VALUES (TO_DATE('2013-5-19 09:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 
TO_DATE('2013-5-19 11:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'));

SELECT start_time, end_time FROM appointment;

SELECT MAX(end_time) FROM appointment 
WHERE TO_CHAR(end_time,'yyyy-mm-dd')=
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2013-5-19', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cut off the time in a date using `trunc(date)`

So if you want the biggest timestamp for a given day you can

```
SELECT MAX(end_date)
  FROM appointment
 WHERE TRUNC(end_date) = to_date('19-05-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') -- <<< users input
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a function such as TRUNC in the WHERE clause may not let the optimizer use indexes on that column (unless, of course, you have a function-based index for that particular function and column).  I've found that in a case similar to this where I needed to find all the rows in a table matching a particular date (only the date components YYYY, MM, and DD supplied) a ranged comparison could be used:

```
DECLARE
  dtSome_date  DATE := TO_DATE('19-MAY-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT *
                 FROM APPOINTMENT e
                 WHERE e.END_TIME BETWEEN dtSome_date
                                      AND dtSome_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND)
  LOOP
    ...whatever...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.